# Need to create sub-domain type of url based on username

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am posting this question after struggling for 2 weeks on this.I am working on a **Laravel** project and I am stuck with a feature which I need to have on the project.

Actually I want to have dynamic URL generation for each user based on their username. Like slack does.

Let's say my domain is `example.com`
And suppose one user registers whose username is `ryan` then I want to have URL like `ryan.example.com`
And when the site is running with this type of URL, it should work for that logged in user. So I will also need some mechanism in my Laravel project which can get me user id or other user details from that url sagment.

What I have tried so far is:
I put the following code in Laravel's `Route.php` file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.example.com'], function () {
   Route::get('/', function ($account) {
        return $account;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a [subdomain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) support in routing out of the box. From the official documentation,

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

The account portion is not hardcoded. It is dynamic. So you can put various logic inside it. For example, if I want to access `ryan.example.com` then you will need to check whether I am really Ryan or not. You can also use middleware like you can use for other routes.

Also check that you can use $account variable in functions. If you wish then you can use that $account to get "user id or other user details from that url segment."

I hope this answer will be enough to get you started. If you get stuck somewhere then share with us again with any specific problem and we will try to help you.

Comment: Hi @nabil, thank you for the head start. Will this work for all users signing up with the site? If `stephny` registered and then login with the site, the URL will be `stephny.example.com`

Should I make any changes in vhosts file?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I use apache and I didn't need to change anything in vhosts when I worked on a hobby project. But your circumstances might be different.